# Regex specification on a certain syntax problem

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting, routes

I keep getting this really annoying error:

```
E: Error parsing configuration files:
    - routes: Error loading file: while parsing a quoted scalar
          in ".magento/routes.yaml", line 14, column 1
        found unknown escape character
          in ".magento/routes.yaml", line 14, column 31
```

My file is fairly simple. Please find it below:

```
# The routes of the project.
#
# Each route describes how an incoming URL is going to be processed.

    #"http://{default}/":
    #    type: upstream
    #    upstream: "mymagento:php"
    
    
        http://{default}/:
            type: upstream
            redirects:
            paths:
        "^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\?)|(/\?[a-z])|(/\?[a-z]=))?$": { to: "https://www.example.com/", regexp: true }
```

I've tried using double quotes and single quotes and i've also tried to escape line 14 column 1 with `\/`

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but at this point i'm losing the plot. Need help here. Thanks in advance.

```
# The routes of the project.
#
# Each route describes how an incoming URL is going to be processed.

#"http://{default}/":
#    type: upstream
#    upstream: "mymagento:php"




   

    http://{default}/:
    type: upstream
    redirects:
    paths: ^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\\?)|(/\\?[a-z])|(/\\?[a- 
    z]=))?$ : { to: https:///www.example.com/, regexp: true }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes are used for escaping in yaml, so you must escape them with another backslash; replace `\` with `\\`, and don't use quotes around the value:

```
paths: ^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\\?)|(/\\?[a-z])|(/\\?[a-z]=))?$
```

Your yaml syntax is either wrong or foreign to me. I suspect it should be:

```
http:
    type:      upstream
    redirects:
    paths:     ^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\\?)|(/\\?[a-z])|(/\\?[a-z]=))?$
    to:        https://www.example.com/
    regexp:    true
```

Comment: oh man... i'm so stupid right now. thank you... i don't know why i didn't process that.

Comment: @Singleton no, unless you want actual quote characters in the value string. TBH I've never seen yml syntax like that and I don't even understand what it's trying to represent. Bottom line: escape the backslashes. There may be more issues.

Comment: let me try it real quick

Comment: So that worked for those errors now it's complaining about E: Error parsing configuration files:
    - routes: Error loading file: mapping values are not allowed in this context
          in ".magento/routes.yaml", line 15, column 74

Comment: Basically complaining about the : <<<<

Comment: ughhhhh....oh man... i appreciate your help.. one more error:  E: Error parsing configuration files:
    - routes.key: 'http' doesn't contain a scheme

Comment: Probably because it's https?

Comment: yeah... still getting the error : routes.key: 'http' doesn't contain a scheme  << i tried https as well

Comment: What tool/library is this config for?